# how can i solve this error( request for member printDetails in book which is of non class type int) how can i solve it?

Tags: c++

this is my code it is about class book in c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Book {
private:
    string title;
    int editions;
    string publisherRef;
    double price;
public:
    void setTitle(string t) {
        title = t;
    }
    void setEditions(int e) {
        editions = e;
    }
    void setPublisherRef(string p) {
        publisherRef = p;
    }
    void setPrice(double pr) {
        price = pr;
    }
    string getTitle() const {
        return title;
    }
    int getEditions() const {
        return editions;
    }
    string getPublisherRef() const {
        return publisherRef;
    }
    double getPrice() const {
        return price;
    }
    void printDetails()  {
        cout << "Title: " << title << endl;
        cout << "Editions: " << editions << endl;
        cout << "Publisher reference: " << publisherRef << endl;
        cout << "Price: " << price << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    vector<Book> bookList;
    int choice;
    do {
        cout << "Main menu\n";
        cout << "1. Book\n";
        cout << "0. Exit\n";
        cout << "Enter your choice: ";
        cin >> choice;
        switch (choice) {
            case 1: {
                int bookChoice;
                do {
                    cout << "Book submenu\n";
                    cout << "1. Display\n";
                    cout << "2. Insert\n";
                    cout << "0. Back\n";
                    cout << "Enter your choice: ";
                    cin >> bookChoice;
                    switch (bookChoice) {
                        case 1: {
                            if (bookList.empty()) {
                                cout << "There are no books in the list.\n";
                            } else {
                                cout << "Book list:\n";
                                for ( auto& book : bookList) {
                                    book.printDetails();
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                        case 2: {
                            Book newBook;
                            string title, publisherRef;
                            int editions;
                            double price;
                            cout << "Enter title: ";
                            cin.ignore();
                            getline(cin, title);
                            newBook.setTitle(title);
                            cout << "Enter editions: ";
                            cin >> editions;
                            newBook.setEditions(editions);
                            cout << "Enter publisher reference: ";
                            cin.ignore();
                            getline(cin, publisherRef);
                            newBook.setPublisherRef(publisherRef);
                            cout << "Enter price: ";
                            cin >> price;
                            newBook.setPrice(price);
                            bookList.push_back(newBook);
                            cout << "Book added to the list.\n";
                            break;
                        }
                        case 0: {
                            break;
                        }
                        default: {
                            cout << "Invalid choice. Please try again.\n";
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                } while (bookChoice != 0);
                break;
            }
            case 0: {
                break;
            }
            default: {
                cout << "Invalid choice. Please try again.\n";
                break;
            }
        }
    } while (choice != 0);

    return 0;
}
```

The program defines a Book class with data members and member functions as specified in the prompt. It also defines a main function that creates a vector of Book objects called `bookList`, displays a menu to the user, and allows them to view and add books to the list.

This program about class book show this error ( request for member printDetails in book which is of non class type int)

I am trying to solve this error(( request for member printDetails in book which is of non class type int) ) !

how can i solve this  error in c++?

Comment: Please try to create a [mre] to show us, with emphasis on the *minimal* part. Also please copy-paste the full and complete build-log into the question. And add a comment on the lines where you get errors.

Comment: the line error is 72

Comment: the error was appear here (for ( auto& book : bookList) {
                                    book.printDetails();
                                })

Comment: Is 72 the error code?  Which line is 72?

Comment: First of all, you don't need all that code to exemplify the problem. Secondly, are you sure you copy-pasted the correct code? The code you show [doesn't give the error you claim](https://godbolt.org/z/r4rn3Ke3s) (or any errors at all).

Comment: yes, the error was appear in line 72

Comment: @asdo - The range-for was added in C++11. A guess is that you compile this for an older standard. You need to look for the options your compiler uses, perhaps `-std=c++20`, or so.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you are trying to compile with a default option in your compiler (probably `-std=c++03`), and that causes a few errors including the error in line 71 as you mentioned:

```
SO.cpp:71:45: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘book’ with no type [-fpermissive]
   71 |                                 for ( auto& book : bookList) {
```

This is because the meaning of the [`auto`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto#Notes) keyword changed in the C++11 standard:

> Until C++11, auto had the semantic of a storage duration specifier.

and since C++11:

> For variables, specifies that the type of the variable that is being declared will be automatically deduced from its initializer.

and your code uses it in the C++11 way but you're trying to compile the program according to the rules of the C++03 standard. besides that, there is no such thing as *ranges-based* for loops in C++03 and C++98.

It's easy to fix these errors. Just add the option for C++11 mode. If you use GCC or Clang this should work:

```
g++ -std=c++11 Main.cpp -o Main
```

Of course, you can use newer standards such as C++20 or C++23 if your compiler is up to date. Otherwise, you need to update it. If you're on Windows, I suggest [winlibs](https://winlibs.com/) for downloading the latest version of GCC and Clang/LLVM.